# What does "less so" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> [...] emotions—some positive and helpful (I’ve worked hard and I can
>   ace this presentation;...), others negative and less so (He’s
>   purposely ignoring me;...).

I searched online dictionaries and find just the definition below:

> [less so](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/less_so) Contextual comparative. Modifies another adjective (to
>   which the "so" is a direct anaphoric reference), indicating a lesser
>   degree of the quality in question.

So, Does the sentence above means some emotions are negative and *less nagative*?

https://hbr.org/2013/11/emotional-agility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[...] emotions—some positive and helpful (I’ve worked hard and I can ace this presentation;...), others negative and less so (He’s purposely ignoring me;...).

- some emotions are positive and helpful
- others [other emotions] are negative and less helpful. Alternative: less so.

To avoid repeating the word helpful, the author uses **so.**

If there is an adjective with less or more, you can replace it the second time with so.

Another example: The cake was really very sweet. The cupcakes were less so.

less so [less sweet]

In this type of pattern the "so" means that way and replaces an adjective that has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Less helpful.

> emotions—some **positive** and ***helpful***, others **negative** and
>   ***less so***.